# Forcing the developer to place a non-empty tag in the DialogFragment show method?

Tags: android, android-fragments, instantiation, android-dialogfragment

I want to enforce the use of having a tag used in the show method for a `DialogFragment`:

```
MyDialogFragment fragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(args);
fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), MANDATORY_TAG);
```

Is there a way to enforce this, or throw an error from within the fragment somehow, if `MANDATORY_TAG` is `""` or `null`?

Comment: Simply override show method in your DialogFragmentClass and throw a null pointer exception if the tag is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (tag == null || tag.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Please add the Tag. Tag cannot be null or empty");
        }
```

**Edit:**

```
try {
    MyDialogFragment fragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(args);
    fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), MANDATORY_TAG);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What if I want to throw the error back to where the DialogFragment was called so I know where I forgot to include a tag?

Comment: You can catch this exception where you are calling it and then simply see in the logs where it was being called

Comment: So I don't have to add "throws NullPointerException" to the show override function header or anything?

Comment: Now I am confused as to what the "good practice" is supposed to be here. I do care a lot about learning good practice. If I wanted to throw `IllegalArgumentException` how would I set it up properly?

Comment: @KaliMa - after getting this discussion on distance I've decided to delete all my comments as not to confuse you anymore with a discussion that shouldn't have been started or at least been in a private forum. As far as bad or good practice goes I think you should have a look at some of Oracles tutorials or a book like Bruce Eckel's Thinking in Java for instance.

Comment: @KaliMa - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/ Please follow the link. You will find the tutorials on Exception Handling.